# How can I create a VBA function that will select values from excel and be "drag-able" (i.e. Will have different Inputs based on Active Cell)

Tags: excel, vba, function, input

I am currently trying to create a macro that will crunch out a calculation based on values that are input into a row of excel. I want the function to be able to be repeated with a different row of excel inputs if i drag it down. I am new to programming in VBA and a newbie in programming as a whole so bear with me. The issue I am having it that if i select these inputs and assign them a variable like so:

```
Public Function LC() As Variant

    Dim hw As Double
    hw  = Range("D29").Value
    LC = hw

End Function
```

The Value of "hw" will not change from say D29 to D30 if i move the function down a cell. I know the code above is incorrect for what i am trying to do but i don't know what way the code should be for this case. I have tried other codes based on simple google research but have not had any luck.

Any help would be extremely appreciated so thank you in advance.

Comment: Your function should have [arguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/understanding-named-arguments-and-optional-arguments).

Comment: ^^^Think of a basic formula such as `=SUM(A1:B1)` - if you drag this down the 1s become 2s.

Comment: So if i make a function that does not have arguments there is no way to make them drag down? The issue is, i have about 40 inputs to my code and do not want to have 40 arguments as a result. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: A function such as `Row()` will change without any arguments, you might be able to use `application.caller` but we probably need more details of your set up.

Comment: I essentially have a spread sheet with user entered values from say B1 to Z1 and then at AA1 i have the function in the cell =LC(). This function assigns many of these cells to variables and then calculates LC as results of the inputs. i want be able to copy and paste the entire row down  and then change the input cells so that LC will change in the row with respect to the values in the input cells.

If my explanation is not helpful i can post my sheet. Thank you.

Comment: One option (that I probably wouldn't actually do) is to pass the row number. Another option is to pass the entire range of cells.

Comment: You could do as BigBen suggests, or perhaps use a sub.

Comment: Thank you guys, excuse my complete inexperience with this. How would i go about doling that ( passing the cells ) ??